# Increase UIView's frame size at the left edge

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have an UIView that can grow dynamically in width. The view also have subviews located inside it's bounds.

Default behavior seems to be that when the view's frame grows along the x axis, increasing `frame.size.width`, it always grows at the right edge, keeping the subviews fixed as if there were a fix left margin. However, when I want to expand the view on the left edge this doesn't work because of this behavior. In this case I want it to behave in a mirrored way, as if there were a fix right margin. I could of course "manually" move all subviews so it looks like that is the case, but that seems really awkward since there could be plenty of them.

So I guess the question really is if there is a way to shift a views bounds relative to it's subviews? Is maybe autoresizingMask the way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at the AutoresizingMask property of a UIView subclass :-)

For example, if you have a UILabel called labelVideoTitle, you could set a mask like this :

```
[ labelVideoTitle setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth ];
```

You can by the way add 2 mask at once like :

```
[ labelVideoTitle setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ];
```

Good Luck !

Edit : To increase the parent view frame size at the left edge, you could change too its X position to the left to give the impression wanted ^^ For example if you add 10 pt to the width, try modifying the X origin -10 pt :-)

Comment: When you change x origin to -Xpt the added subviews keep their original placement within their parent. If one subview originally was 10pt from the left edge it will still be 10pt from the left edge.

Comment: And did you try with the mask ?

Comment: Using the mask solves my issue, but would require me to change mask settings for all subviews that exist in the superview. Instead I ended up with a solution that programmatically moves all subviews to the right to simulate that the superview expanded on the left edge.

Answer (score 1):

In interface builder, you can graphically indicate in the CMD-3 (little ruler icon) Size Inspector what each element in your view should do when the parent view is resized: you can indicate which borders (top, left, right, bottom), the given element should "stick to" when the parent view is resized.   You can also indicate whether the given element should itself resize (in either width or height) or stay the same size.    Underneath the hood, this sets the autoresize mask for the UIView element you're editing, but especially for making an element stick to a particular border, Interface Builder is the way to go.

IB Size Inspector also has a neat little animation that shows you the effect on a hypothetical element (little red square) during a resize, given your settings to the left.

Comment: Interface Builder is evil ! don't use it ^^

Comment: Interface Builder is confusing and may be considered evil if you don't spend the time to thoroughly understand the Apple architecture of .xib files, bundles, and how they work.   It is frustrating that not every parameter of every UI object is settable in IB, but once I finally started really understanding "File's Owner" a lightbulb went off and I really enjoy using IB now.   I use a mix -- some interfaces I build programmatically because they have easy frames (0,0,full-width,full-height), but placing frames programmatically on a large view is really, really annoying.

Comment: I think that for beginners it's not a good idea. During start of iPhone dev., lot of persons had problems with IB because it was, like you say, confusing. From scratch is better for me, I think it depends :) By the way, you can place frame with the center.